# $\int_0^3 (x^2 + 1){\rm d}\left[x\right]$ where [.] is gif

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, area

The question requires us to find $\int_0^3 (x^2 + 1){\rm d}\left[x\right]$ where [.] denotes greatest integer function

***My attempt:***
For...
$$\left[x\right] =0\text { , } x\in[0,1) \text { , } x^2+1 \in [1,2)\\
\left[x\right] =1\text { , } x\in[1,2) \text { , } x^2+1 \in [2,5)\\
\left[x\right] =2\text { , } x\in[2,3) \text { , } x^2+1 \in [5,10)\\$$

Plotting them would look like

[image]

The shaded area sums up to 9. So I thought it would give ans 9.

But the original answer key says 17. On onservation, it is visible as the sum of shaded as well as non-shaded area just under it.

Could anyone suggest a method to proceed?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Interesting Integration with respect to $[x]$ where $[\cdot]$ is greatest integer function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3017440/interesting-integration-with-respect-to-x-where-cdot-is-greatest-intege) or [Evalute the definite integral: $\int_{0}^{3} (x^2+1) d[x]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2580938/evalute-the-definite-integral-int-03-x21-dx?noredirect=1) or [Integration involving $d[x]$ instead of dx](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1528267/integration-involving-dx-instead-of-dx).

Answer (score 1):

You can use "integration by parts" to verify

$$\int_0^3 (x^2+1)d[x] = [x](x^2+1)\Bigr|_0^3 - \int_0^3 2x[x]\:dx = 30 - 10 - 3 = 17$$